# C# (Mono) test for C application (Linux) modifies attribute unexpectedly

Tags: c#, c, linux, mono, pinvoke

I'm porting a .dll project from VS to Linux and unluckily tests were written in C#. I'm porting/bit of refactoring them too and I came to this weird situation:

My `TestFixture` imports a function from a .so:

```
[DllImport(LIB_NAME, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern UInt32 function(ref STRUCT structPtr);
```

Then, I have a test which does the following:

```
[Test]
public void ...() {
    ...
    STRUCT structVar = new STRUCT();
    result = function(ref structVar);
    //Check if function result is OK, which ensures the struct should have been properly modified
    Assert.AreEqual(0x00, structVar.externalAttribute1.innerAttribute1); //OK!
    Assert.AreEqual(0x00, structVar.externalAttribute2.innerAttribute1); //FAIL!
    ...
}
```

It is exactly the same `Assert` in both cases and, the **weirdest** thing of it all is that STRUCT contains another externalAttribute of the **same type**, **which is set correctly**.

Output of test is:

```
1) Failed : ...
  Expected: 0
  But was:  108
```

So sure, **one would think it's the function** which sets it to this value, **but** that's actually the **only** line which modifies this attribute:

```
structPtr->externalAttribute.innerAttribute = 0x00;
```

I think it might be related to struct's alignment and **C#**'s Marshalling not being configured correctly:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1,  CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct EXT_STRUCT // externalAttribute
{
    public byte innerAttribute;
    public byte innerAttribute2;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1,  CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct STRUCT {
    EXT_STRUCT externalAttribute1;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    //public string str1;
    public byte[] str1;
    public uint attrLong;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    //public string str2;
    public byte[] str2;

    EXT_STRUCT externalAttribute2;
}
```

(As requested by @DavidHeffernan), here's the struct defined in **C**:

```
typedef struct EXT_STRUCT {
    unsigned char extAttr1;
    unsigned char extAttr2;
} EXT_STRUCT;

typedef struct STRUCT {
  EXT_STRUCT        extAttr1;
  unsigned char     str1[32];
  unsigned long     attrLong;

  unsigned char     str2[32];
  EXT_STRUCT        extAttr2;
} STRUCT;
```

Those **`byte`** are being represented as an **`unsigned char`** in `C`, so I think there shouldn't be a problem at first, but it's the only thing which makes sense to me. I can't, however, debug it and see what's happening.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**: The struct has some str members which would theoretically be marshalled from this:

```
unsigned char[32];
```

I've seen the value of externalAttribute1 is correct, while externalAttribute2 is the one acting weirdly. The C code does basically that:

```
...
structPtr->externalAttribute1.innerAttribute = 0x02;
structPtr->externalAttribute1.innerAttribute2 = 0x20;
memset(structPtr->str1, ' ', sizeof(structPtr->str1));
memcpy(structPtr->str1, STR1_VALUE, strlen(STR1_VALUE));
...
memset(structPtr->str2, ' ', sizeof(structPtr->str2)); // OK without this
memcpy(structPtr->str2, STR2_VALUE, strlen(STR2_VALUE)); // OK without this
structPtr->externalAttribute2.innerAttribute = 0x00;
structPtr->externalAttribute2.innerAttribute2 = 0x05;
```

If I comment out the **`str2`**'s `memcpy` and `memset`, the value of externalAttribute2 is perfectly fine, no matter whether they are used on `str1` or not. I've checked the size of `STR2_VALUE` and it's 30 chars long (31 with `\0`) so it shouldn't write out of its boundaries (32 bytes).

It definitely seems to be writing over innerAttribute however, since assertion's failure changes to this when I only use the `memset`:

```
Expected: 0
But was:  32 // 32 = ' ' (ASCII)
```

When using the `memcpy`, it was a **108** (`l` in ASCII), and there's an `l` present in position 28.

Although I think I know where the problem is, I don't seem to be able to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE**: I'd love to **debug** this and see memory contents to track down the problem. The point is that after struggling with **`Mono`** a lot and quitting the idea of using **`MonoDevelop`** (it simply crashes on project load when I build it from source, and Ubuntu's MD version is so old that **`NUnit3`**'s addin is not even listed), I'm now running tests using a simple **`bash`** script with some folder/file management and basically these two important lines:

```
...
mcs -unsafe ${test_source_input} ${definitions_file} -target:library -r:${nunit_lib_name} -out:${test_lib_output}
...
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./ mono ${console_runner} ${test_filename}.dll
...
```

The point is that I expected to be able to use **`GDB`** but, to my surprise and even having read [Mono Debugging docs](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/guidedebugger/#preparing-your-program), I can't figure out how the heck can I debug the tests.

I've tried that **`mdb`** stuff but it doesn't even look like what I want (stepping through code in order to inspect variables and memory contents).

Comment: Compare the size of the method that is working against the method that is not working.  The method that is failing externalAttribute ias not being allocated any memory.  It is a structure inside another structure and is just a pointer.  So you have to allocate memory.

Comment: @jdweng I assigned `= new STRUCT2();` to both of those attributes and it's still doing the same.

Comment: This sort of question is easy enough to answer for a seasoned pinvoke coder, but it does need a full specification and some clarity. That's lacking here. Lots of details missing. Not least being the C code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you could ask for the details you'd need to answer this. The code is just what it is (I changed names for obvious reasons). C code didn't seem relevant for me until, as I commented to jdweng , I noticed there were weird stuff with the memcpy/memset. I'm adding it now

Comment: I'd start by offering complete, yet minimal, example C code to show how to call the function in question, populate the structs in question. Then your attempts to match that in C#. This is an interop question and so we need clear sight of the details of both sides of the interop boundary.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The only thing that was missing was what the C function code was and what was it doing. I added it now. The way it's being called/marshalled was already in the question. Thanks

Comment: No. You've not shown the struct declarations in the C code. It's now been 3 days since you asked, and you've not had any proper response yet. That's because the question is poor.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't think it's poor in any case. Maybe there was some info missing but, besides having a lot of info, it's as simple as requesting more instead of being such arrogant. Thanks

Comment: You need to develop a thicker skin and learn how to cope with constructive criticism. You've had no useful response, which indicates a poor question. Stick to your guns if you want, tell yourself the question is fine, but the evidence suggests it isn't and you aren't any closer to understanding. If anything your are further away due to jdweng's misleading response.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have accepted **constructive** criticism, so should you. However, your comments are arrogant and there's absolutely no need. I've added the info I've been requested, but I can't foresee what people need to know about this piece of code in order to help me. That's why I told you to request something specific, and I expanded the question when you did. Now I'll keep waiting until someone tries to help me, either adding possible solutions or asking for clarity of some **specific** part of the code. Thanks

Comment: Never mind. Good luck.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you. Feel free to post your own answer. You now have all the info you requested.

Comment: I'm rather confused by the use of strings when the C code uses `unsigned char` arrays. I'd expect `unsigned char` arrays to indicate binary rather than text. I don't think that the structs should be packed. I presume that your platform's default `CharSet` is `CharSet.Ansi`. But you still have not shown complete information. You have removed part of the C# structure. Why are you making this so hard. Can't you show a [mcve]?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164555/discussion-between-jjimenezg93-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I posted the solution since I finally found it out. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, thanks to [@David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan), I got the solution.

It looks like `uint` is stored in 4 bytes and the attribute of the struct that was between the two strings was `unsigned long` (8 bytes) in C while `uint` (4 bytes) in C#. That is obviously a nonsense but I didn't even care about it since it's working in Windows for some reason **I can't understand**.

The fix was as simple as changing the C# struct to this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct EXT_STRUCT
{
    public byte innAttr1;
    public byte innAttr2;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct STRUCT
{
    public EXT_STRUCT extAttr1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string str1;
    public ulong attrLong; // That was uint

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string str2;

    public EXT_STRUCT extAttr2;
}
```

That was messing Marshalling and it explains perfectly why it was inserting a `108` in the first byte of the `extAttr2`:

`108` = `l` (ASCII) -> there was an `l` in the position 28 of `str2`'s value.
28+4 = 32 -> the memcpy was copying that `l` in `extAttr2.innAttr1`, since the memory layout was:

```
|   Field  | C bytes | C# bytes |
|----------|---------|----------|
| extAttr1 |   0-1   |    0-1   |
|   str1   |   2-33  |   2-33   |
| attrLong |  34-41  |   34-37  |
|   str2   |  42-73  |   38-69  |
| extAttr2 |  74-75  |   70-71  |
```

It makes sense now, although we **won't be able to run our tests** without modifying code **on 32-bit** platform if we want to, indeed.

Comment: There is nothing nonsensical about this whatsoever. It's exactly as expected, and exactly as I explained to you in chat. Your C# struct will be incorrect if you ever attempt to compile for a 32 bit process.

Comment: Yes, I meant it's nonsense (from our side) to use `uint` in C# marshalling when we are using `long` in C. It works on VS because in Windows it's still 32-bit, indeed you mentioned this in chat. The 32/64 bit compilation is definitely annoying but I guess I'll figure out something along the way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, on Window C `long` is 32 bits even in a 64 bit process

Comment: That's what I mean. C's `unsigned long` in Windows is 32-bit even on x64, so that was mapping fine to C#'s `uint` (also 32-bit). On the other hand, Linux64 uses 64-bit for the `unsigned long` in C and `uint` in C# is 32-bit, there's the mismatch.

Answer (score -3):

Code should look like this

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public struct EXT_STRUCT //External attribute
        {
            public byte innerAttribute; //The inner attribute being modified
            public byte innerAttribute2; //Another inner attribute having exactly the same issue
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public struct STRUCT
        {
            public int i1;
            public int i2;
            public int i3;
            public EXT_STRUCT externalAttribute;

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EXT_STRUCT s1 = new EXT_STRUCT();
            IntPtr s1Ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(EXT_STRUCT)));
            //use StructureToPtr only when sending values to c++
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(s1, s1Ptr, true);
            int size1 = Marshal.SizeOf(s1); ;

            STRUCT s2 = new STRUCT();
            s2.externalAttribute = new EXT_STRUCT();
            IntPtr s2Ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(STRUCT)));
            //use StructureToPtr only when sending values to c++
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(s2, s2Ptr, true);
            int size2 = Marshal.SizeOf(s2);


            STRUCT s3 = new STRUCT();
            IntPtr s3Ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(STRUCT)));
            //call c++

            Marshal.PtrToStructure(s3Ptr, s3); 



        }
```

Comment: I don't understand, what are `size1` and `size2` used for? Thanks.

Comment: They are instances of the structure which allocates memory to the objects.

Comment: are they instances? Are they actually pointers then? Anyway, they aren't used at all after being defined so, what's the point? Sorry if it's too obvious but I'm not experienced in C# and this looks weird for me.

Comment: What I mean is, I know it returns the size of the object but this would be useful for a `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` for example, I don't see how can it help me in this particular case, in which I'm passing a ref to the object to an unmanaged function. Thanks

Comment: I updated the code for passing objects to c++.  c# is managed code and to pass variables to c++ you have to move the c# structure to un-managed memory space.  So you have to meet both c# and c++ requirements.Performing new allows c# to read and write structure.  Otherwise c# will test that variable is not allocated and give an error.  You also need the AllocHGlobal to allocate the structure in un-managed memory.Then StructureToPtr which moves the intialized structure to un-manged. You do not need StructureToPtr if you are using the structure to return values.  When return you need PtrToStruct.

Comment: Updated code for return object from c++.  You need to allocate the memory using new Struct() before calling.  c++.  The structure is passed on the execution stack and memory allocated in c++ is lost when you return from the call.  So you must pre-allocate the memory before the call.  I'm assuming the structure is EXT_STRUCT is in-line and not a pointer.

Comment: I'm now trying this new stuff you said, thank you. However, there are some `public string strAttribute` inside my `STRUCT` and I have `memcpy`/`memset` in my C function right before `externalAttribute`. I see weird stuff regarding this memory copies/set (the value inside `externalAttribute` seems to coincide with some of this characters), so could I be not marshalling it correctly? (`[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]` They are declared as `unsigned char[32]`.

Comment: Usually declare as byte[].In c# strings don't have fixed sizes and each item needs a size so the start location of next item in structure can be determined. Either make the length of the byte[] fixed (larger than actual data.usually use something like 256) or you precede the array with a property integer length.Or with a char[] in C you terminate the end of array with '\0' (in c# that is what ByValTStr does).But then the next item starts with the byte following the '\0' and the whole size of the structure is hard to calculate.If you only have 1 string then put it as last item in structure.

Comment: I would make then byte[32] instead of strings.

Comment: This is another one of your answers where you throw arbitrary IntPtr and manual marshaling at some poor asker that thinks you have experience of this. You've never written pinvoke code in your life. Pity the poor asker.